# Ошибка в SSMS - цепочка сертификатов выпущена центром сертификации, не имеющим доверия. Как решить?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки SSMS и SQL Server Express, попытался зайти в SSMS и подключиться к серверу (коим является мой пк), вылезла ошибка показанная на изображении. Может кто знает как это решить? Пробовал переустановить и SSMS и SQL Server Express - результат нулевой.

Comment: Подключите сервер к Инету и через MS Update выполните установку обновления корневых центров сертификации. Если не помогает - попробуйте добавить сертификат выпустившего центра в хранилище доверенных центров.

Answer (score 0):

в студии при установке соединения нужно нажать подробнее, и поставить галочку "доверять сертификату"